# Duplicate system PATH variable (snap/bin:/snap/bin)

Tags: snap, bashrc, zsh, golang

When I run `echo $PATH` the duplicate output **snap/bin:/snap/bin** appears at the end and seems unusual.

```
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Is this duplication undesired?
If so, how can this be changed?

Answer (score 4):

Probably, in your `~/.bashrc` or in your `~/.profile` there is a command that adds `/snap/bin` to the `$PATH` without previously checking if it is still in the `$PATH`.

Consider that duplicated entries in `$PATH` variable doesn't have any impacts when you run a command that is in your `$PATH`. Slowdown may be present on the other hand when you run a command not in `$PATH` (because the command search is performed, uselessly, two or more times when duplicated entries are present), even though I think it is difficult to perceive this slowdown.
Duplicate entries are also a little bit annoying when you want to visually check your `$PATH` variable.

If you want to avoid duplicated entries in your `$PATH`, you can add this command in your `~/.profile` file (that is [the best location for environmental variables](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-config-files-should-be-used-for-setting-bash-environment-variables/183956#183956)):

```
# remove duplicated paths in PATH variable
PATH="$(printf "%s" "$PATH" | awk -v RS=':' '!a[$1]++ {if (NR > 1) printf RS; printf $1}')"
```

This command use `awk` to identify every item in the `$PATH` variable (they are separated by means of the `:` character) and rebuild the `$PATH` variable avoiding re-adding duplicated folders. It also preserves the original sort of the folders inside the `$PATH` variable.

You can open `~/.profile` with your preferred text editor. If you open it by terminal, you don't need `sudo` because it belongs to your user.

Comment: Thank you a tonne. That makes some things a lot clearer in my mind about what's going on with environment vaiables, bash.rc and .profile - if I could ask, if .profile is the best place, then why would other commands specify ~/.bashrc ? Such as,  echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-config-files-should-be-used-for-setting-bash-environment-variables/183956#183956 and https://superuser.com/a/183980

Comment: If you are using zsh, maybe this link can give you some further info: https://superuser.com/a/187673

Comment: Thanks. That should help.